# How can I extract the frequency (in Hz) of a topic inside a rosbag?

Tags: ros, frequency, rosbag

I have a rosbag file, which has recorded messages of several topics.

Is there a way I can know the frequency at which the messages of a particular topic were published (and recorded)?

when I do `rosbag info` I get something like

```
path:        the.bag
version:     2.0
duration:    60.0s
start:       Jul 01 2021 16:58:10.27 (1625158690.27)
end:         Jul 01 2021 16:59:10.27 (1625158750.27)
size:        6.1 GB
messages:    37131
compression: none [1188/1188 chunks]
types:       sensing_msgs/type1    [621fdfebbc8899ba27ee5fed4fcccaee]
             sensing_msgs/type2 [cf69c51b4a51518b0ef7e36af744fc70]
             sensor_msgs/Image       [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
topics:      /mycamera/image         1187 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image      
             /mymessage1            29944 msgs    : sensing_msgs/type1
             /mymessage2/input       6000 msgs    : sensing_msgs/type2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know message publication is continuous throughout the recording frequency is just `total_messages / time`. Otherwise you can get frequency via `rosbag play <bag_file>` and `rostopic hz <topic_name>`

Answer (score 1):

rosbag command has the option to do it.

```
rosbag info <bag_name> --freq
```